# Database not removing element due to DateTime Error

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, datetime

I am currently using entity framework and trying to delete an entry from a database table.

I am using a Delete function and check for an instance where the serial number is equal to the serial number passed in.

I pass in a JSON string with the serial number of test_server, and attempt to remove the test_server index from my HistoryData Table.

HistoryTable has serial number and a timestamp properties.

The problem is, I am getting an error that says Additional information:

```
The 'Timestamp' property on 'HistoryData' could not be set to a 'System.String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.DateTime'.
```

when trying to remove the element.

Any ideas as to why this could be happening?

Code for delete method

```
public void Delete(string serialNumber)
    {
        db.HistoryDatas.Remove(db.HistoryDatas.SingleOrDefault(s => s.SerialNumber.Equals(serialNumber)));
        db.SaveChanges();
    }


Database table
    SerialNumber           TimeStamp
    test_server            2014-05-09 13:14:54
    test_server            2014-05-09 13:15:54
```

Comment: My guess is that you have some relationship constraint to another entity, so a delete isn't really happening.  But that's just a guess.  It would help if you could create an example that fully reproduces the issue.  Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help center.  Thanks.

Comment: Including table definitions for your table and all other tables related either directly or indirectly.